# Targeting multiple elements of a class in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am attempting to select multiple elements of a table with a specific class.  What is the correct way to do it as I do not believe I've done it right in the example below?
I want both the th's and td's of class .myTable to have the specified styles applied.

Keep in mind I may want to do something like this elsewhere, for instance, all of the p's and spans of div with class .myDiv to have a background color of blue or something like that.  So not a solution specific to tables.

```
.myTable th, td
{
    border: 1px;
    border-color: #D3D3D3;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

EDIT:
My apologies as I realize the question was not clear.  In my situation, the elements `th` and `td` are children of a `table` with the class of `.myTable`.  The `th` and `td` elements do not have any classes directly applied to them in my scenario.

Comment: If you want a generic solution, why not just use `.myClass`?

Comment: Also: you're getting answers about two different scenarios, you should add your markup to clarify what you mean.

Comment: Please, read [the CSS 'Selectors Level 3' documentation from the W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors). It will help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need this (add `.myTable` before `td` as well):

```
.myTable th, .myTable td
{
    border: 1px;
    border-color: #D3D3D3;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Not quite, I quote: *`th`s and `td`s of class `.myTable`* (admittedly with some grammatical/formatting correction).

Comment: @David: Not quite what? The example provided will apply styles to all `th` and `td` tags within a `.myTable` class container. (Which is what the OP requested.)

Comment: No, what the OP requested (as written in his question) is `td` and `th` elements of the class `myTable`; the `th` and `td` elements *themselves* should (again, as written in the question) have those classes, not their ancestor element.

Comment: I think judging by the css that he has, he's trying to style things inside a table with a class of myTable. OP should provide html to make things more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
th.myTable, td.myTable {
    border: 1px;
    border-color: #D3D3D3;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;

}
```

Comment: He didn't post his markup, but judging from his css, he has a table with a class of myTable. Your answer would style th and td tags with a class of myTable.

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it.

```
.myTable th, .myTable td
```

What you're doing is selecting all the th tags in .myTable and all the td tags on the page.

Comment: What's the difference between `.myTable th` and `th.myTable`?

Comment: I believe that means all th elements on the page with the class of .myTable.

Comment: @DMase05: `.myTable th` will apply styles to all `th` tags within a container that has the `.myTable` class. `th.myTable` will apply styles to all `th` tags that have the `.myTable` class.

Comment: The element *after* a space is a descendent element of the element *before* the space; therefore `.myTable th` is looking for a `th` element within an element of the class `myTable`. Whereas `th.myTable` is looking for a `th` element with the class of `myTable`.

Answer (score 0):

If .myTable class is a parent of both th and td, you have to use .myTable th, .myTable td. If that's right, it should work. I also think you should read a little bit about "specificity" in CSS. If you're editing a Theme or Template file, sometimes this kind of thing won't work because of another rule that's more "specific" than yours. ID's, for example, are more specific than Classes. Check that out and it will avoid future problems to you!